# Make a HTTP request without a browser or curl

Tags: http, request

I got this on a jobs interview :

Make a HTTP request to https://spnagios.storpool.com/confupd/meow.php with parameter "hi" to equal two_unique from the previous task, without a browser or curl and you'll get an email address.

The answer to the previous task was 487 .

Now you might say : Well if you can't figure this out you are probably not fit for the job .
Well you are probably right but I still want to know how it is done and what is the answer so I can get the email :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the interviewer intended to test your knowledge of TCP networking and application level protocols. In this scenario, you can typically use any tool that allows you to establish a raw TCP socket, and then send the application protocol messages manually.

See some eaxamples below.

Using `telnet`

```sh
➜  ~ telnet spnagios.storpool.com 80
Trying 185.117.80.38...
Connected to https-sof.storpool.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /confupd/meow.php HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 10:33:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Using `netcat`

```sh
➜  ~ nc spnagios.storpool.com 80
GET /confupd/meow.php HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 10:39:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried with telnet and even if i try with : 
GET /confupd/meow.php/hi=487 HTTP/1.0    (because 487 was the answer from the previous task i had to do )
I dont get results

Comment: sorry. i just focused on the part about sending the message without the usual tools. In my example I use http but the original URL is over https which will be port 443. Also the client side will need some way to verify the certificate which is out of scope of the tools i mentioned above. A better options will be to use "openssl"

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) or any other rest api development tools to make http requests.

For example you can make http request in Postman like below:

https://spnagios.storpool.com/confupd/meow.php/hi=487

Comment: Hi, your way end with : 401 Authorization Required
And i can't find any mail in the error

Comment: As in question it is mentioned that parameter "hi" to equal *two_unique* from the previous task. I think you should try this also: `https://spnagios.storpool.com/confupd/meow.php/hi=487487`

Comment: i get this :
Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

Comment: If the interviewer restrict the use of browser and curl, I think Postman, Insomnia, etc. will also be forbidden as well. I think the interviewer wanted to know your understanding behind HTTP request, such as using `telnet` or `netcat`, just like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61499940/9844546

Answer (score 0):

[root@alma 2_http]# openssl s_client -connect spnagios.storpool.com:443

GET https://spnagios.storpool.com/localweb/meow.php?hi=5 HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Sun, 24 Sep 2023 10:46:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close

Secret email address ****@storpool.com
closed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).